# How to embed luasql.sqlite3 in a statically linked C program?

Tags: c, sqlite, lua, luasql

The `luasql.sqlite3` module has been compiled into my C program successfully, statically linked. But, it seems the module has not been registered yet. The call of `require 'luasql.sqlite3'` always fails in Lua scripts.

Some other modules call `luaL_register` to register themselves. But `luaL_register` is not called in `luaopen_luasql_sqlite3`. How do I register `luasql.sqlite3` in this case?

I use Lua-5.1.5.

[The source code of luaopen_luasql_sqlite3 is at the bottom](https://github.com/LuaDist/luasql-sqlite3/blob/master/src/ls_sqlite3.c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way of putting luaopen_ functions into the package.preload table.

```
lua_getfield(L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "package");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "preload");
lua_pushcfunction(L, luaopen_socket_core);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "socket.core");
```

Answer (score 1):

`require` works with DLLs because it uses the given module name to track down the DLL and fetch a specific function from that DLL. It doesn't work automatically for static libraries because C and C++ have no introspection; you can't dymanically find a C function that starts with `luaopen_`.

As such, you need to tell the Lua package system that you want to make this module available to Lua code. You do this by sticking the `luaopen_` function in the `package.preload` table, giving it the name that the module will be called.

Comment: thanks. I call luaopen_ function directly in C. luaL_requiref function is not available in lua5.1. Is there a convenient way to put luaopen_ function into package.preload table?

Answer (score 0):

This works with LuaSQL 2.4 and Lua 5.1 AND newer...

In C

```
/* Execute the luasql initializers */
lua_getglobal(L, "package");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "preload");
lua_pushcfunction(L, luaopen_luasql_postgres);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "luasql.postgres");
lua_pop(L, 2);

lua_getglobal(L, "package");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "preload");
lua_pushcfunction(L, luaopen_luasql_mysql);
lua_setfield(L, -2, "luasql.mysql");
lua_pop(L, 2);
```

etc, etc for each DBI interface you need...and THEN, in your Lua script(s)

```
 local luasql = require "luasql.postgres";
 pg = luasql.postgres();
 dev, err = pg:connect( netidb_conninfo );
 if err then .....
```

Please note you will have to prototype luaopen_luasql_postgres(), etc yourself for C
to compile successfully as the library doesn't have prototypes for the functions defined
for external use.